# How do I take input from an UI and place it into a migrations folder for contract deployment?

Tags: solidity, truffle, ethereumjs, react, openzeppelin

Essentially I am in the process of designing an app that allows users to deploy a simple ERC721 smart contract to the web. I am struggling however to find a solution to retrieving user-inputted data from the UI and placing it within the deployment migrations folder before the user deploys the contact.
React and drizzle are the Front End dev tools I am using.

```
const MusicRightsNFT = artifacts.require("MusicRightsNFT");

module.exports = function () {
  deployer.deploy(MusicRightsNFT, 'Name', 'Artist');
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to trigger an event in your front end that will catch these value and store them in the state until you process them.

```
*REACT*
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}>
```

This will print out the value in the devtool console anytime the value change.

To send your transaction to the network, Your app will need a Provider like metamask that you can load using web.

You should deploy a contract that deploys contract on behalf of the user.

Deploying the contract for yourself is done with all the dev tools.

Deploying contract from a front end is done within a contract.

You should have a function in your contract that deploys contract.